# paypal ipn script won't work

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

Not quite sure what the problem is, but I hope someone can help me. I went to https://www.paypaltech.com/SG2/ and used their tool to create a php script that writes to the db (MySQL). Here is the exact script it gave me back (except for the credentials, obviously):

```
<?php

// Revision Notes
// 11/04/11 - changed post back url from https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr to https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
// For more info see below:
// https://www.x.com/content/bulletin-ip-address-expansion-paypal-services
// "ACTION REQUIRED: if you are using IPN (Instant Payment Notification) for Order Management and your IPN listener script is behind a firewall that uses ACL (Access Control List) rules which restrict outbound traffic to a limited number of IP addresses, then you may need to do one of the following: 
// To continue posting back to https://www.paypal.com  to perform IPN validation you will need to update your firewall ACL to allow outbound access to *any* IP address for the servers that host your IPN script
// OR Alternatively, you will need to modify  your IPN script to post back IPNs to the newly created URL https://ipnpb.paypal.com using HTTPS (port 443) and update firewall ACL rules to allow outbound access to the ipnpb.paypal.com IP ranges (see end of message)."


/////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////Begin Script below./////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

// If testing on Sandbox use:
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

//$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://ipnpb.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);


// assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$business = $_POST['business'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$mc_gross = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$receiver_id = $_POST['receiver_id'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$num_cart_items = $_POST['num_cart_items'];
$payment_date = $_POST['payment_date'];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$payment_type = $_POST['payment_type'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_gross = $_POST['payment_gross'];
$payment_fee = $_POST['payment_fee'];
$settle_amount = $_POST['settle_amount'];
$memo = $_POST['memo'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$txn_type = $_POST['txn_type'];
$payer_status = $_POST['payer_status'];
$address_street = $_POST['address_street'];
$address_city = $_POST['address_city'];
$address_state = $_POST['address_state'];
$address_zip = $_POST['address_zip'];
$address_country = $_POST['address_country'];
$address_status = $_POST['address_status'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$tax = $_POST['tax'];
$option_name1 = $_POST['option_name1'];
$option_selection1 = $_POST['option_selection1'];
$option_name2 = $_POST['option_name2'];
$option_selection2 = $_POST['option_selection2'];
$for_auction = $_POST['for_auction'];
$invoice = $_POST['invoice'];
$custom = $_POST['custom'];
$notify_version = $_POST['notify_version'];
$verify_sign = $_POST['verify_sign'];
$payer_business_name = $_POST['payer_business_name'];
$payer_id =$_POST['payer_id'];
$mc_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$mc_fee = $_POST['mc_fee'];
$exchange_rate = $_POST['exchange_rate'];
$settle_currency  = $_POST['settle_currency'];
$parent_txn_id  = $_POST['parent_txn_id'];
$pending_reason = $_POST['pending_reason'];
$reason_code = $_POST['reason_code'];


// subscription specific vars

$subscr_id = $_POST['subscr_id'];
$subscr_date = $_POST['subscr_date'];
$subscr_effective  = $_POST['subscr_effective'];
$period1 = $_POST['period1'];
$period2 = $_POST['period2'];
$period3 = $_POST['period3'];
$amount1 = $_POST['amount1'];
$amount2 = $_POST['amount2'];
$amount3 = $_POST['amount3'];
$mc_amount1 = $_POST['mc_amount1'];
$mc_amount2 = $_POST['mc_amount2'];
$mc_amount3 = $_POST['mcamount3'];
$recurring = $_POST['recurring'];
$reattempt = $_POST['reattempt'];
$retry_at = $_POST['retry_at'];
$recur_times = $_POST['recur_times'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

//auction specific vars

$for_auction = $_POST['for_auction'];
$auction_closing_date  = $_POST['auction_closing_date'];
$auction_multi_item  = $_POST['auction_multi_item'];
$auction_buyer_id  = $_POST['auction_buyer_id'];



//DB connect creds and email 
$notify_email =  "hidden_for_StackOverflow";         //email address to which debug emails are sent to
$DB_Server = "hidden_for_StackOverflow"; //your MySQL Server
$DB_Username = "hidden_for_StackOverflow"; //your MySQL User Name
$DB_Password = "hidden_for_StackOverflow"; //your MySQL Password
$DB_DBName = "hidden_for_StackOverflow"; //your MySQL Database Name


if (!$fp) {
// HTTP ERROR
} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {



//create MySQL connection
$Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password)
or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());


//select database
$Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect)
or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());


$fecha = date("m")."/".date("d")."/".date("Y");
$fecha = date("Y").date("m").date("d");

//check if transaction ID has been processed before
$checkquery = "select txnid from paypal_payment_info where txnid='".$txn_id."'";
$sihay = mysql_query($checkquery) or die("Duplicate txn id check query failed:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
$nm = mysql_num_rows($sihay);
if ($nm == 0){

//execute query



    if ($txn_type == "cart"){
    $strQuery = "insert into paypal_payment_info(paymentstatus,buyer_email,firstname,lastname,street,city,state,zipcode,country,mc_gross,mc_fee,memo,paymenttype,paymentdate,txnid,pendingreason,reasoncode,tax,datecreation) values ('".$payment_status."','".$payer_email."','".$first_name."','".$last_name."','".$address_street."','".$address_city."','".$address_state."','".$address_zip."','".$address_country."','".$mc_gross."','".$mc_fee."','".$memo."','".$payment_type."','".$payment_date."','".$txn_id."','".$pending_reason."','".$reason_code."','".$tax."','".$fecha."')";

     $result = mysql_query($strQuery) or die("Cart - paypal_payment_info, Query failed:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
     for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_cart_items; $i++) {
         $itemname = "item_name".$i;
         $itemnumber = "item_number".$i;
         $on0 = "option_name1_".$i;
         $os0 = "option_selection1_".$i;
         $on1 = "option_name2_".$i;
         $os1 = "option_selection2_".$i;
         $quantity = "quantity".$i;

         $struery = "insert into paypal_cart_info(txnid,itemnumber,itemname,os0,on0,os1,on1,quantity,invoice,custom) values ('".$txn_id."','".$_POST[$itemnumber]."','".$_POST[$itemname]."','".$_POST[$on0]."','".$_POST[$os0]."','".$_POST[$on1]."','".$_POST[$os1]."','".$_POST[$quantity]."','".$invoice."','".$custom."')";
         $result = mysql_query($struery) or die("Cart - paypal_cart_info, Query failed:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());

     }
    }



    else{
     $strQuery = "insert into paypal_payment_info(paymentstatus,buyer_email,firstname,lastname,street,city,state,zipcode,country,mc_gross,mc_fee,itemnumber,itemname,os0,on0,os1,on1,quantity,memo,paymenttype,paymentdate,txnid,pendingreason,reasoncode,tax,datecreation) values ('".$payment_status."','".$payer_email."','".$first_name."','".$last_name."','".$address_street."','".$address_city."','".$address_state."','".$address_zip."','".$address_country."','".$mc_gross."','".$mc_fee."','".$item_number."','".$item_name."','".$option_name1."','".$option_selection1."','".$option_name2."','".$option_selection2."','".$quantity."','".$memo."','".$payment_type."','".$payment_date."','".$txn_id."','".$pending_reason."','".$reason_code."','".$tax."','".$fecha."')";
     $result = mysql_query("insert into paypal_payment_info(paymentstatus,buyer_email,firstname,lastname,street,city,state,zipcode,country,mc_gross,mc_fee,itemnumber,itemname,os0,on0,os1,on1,quantity,memo,paymenttype,paymentdate,txnid,pendingreason,reasoncode,tax,datecreation) values ('".$payment_status."','".$payer_email."','".$first_name."','".$last_name."','".$address_street."','".$address_city."','".$address_state."','".$address_zip."','".$address_country."','".$mc_gross."','".$mc_fee."','".$item_number."','".$item_name."','".$option_name1."','".$option_selection1."','".$option_name2."','".$option_selection2."','".$quantity."','".$memo."','".$payment_type."','".$payment_date."','".$txn_id."','".$pending_reason."','".$reason_code."','".$tax."','".$fecha."')") or die("Default - paypal_payment_info, Query failed:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
    }


    // send an email in any case
 echo "Verified";
     mail($notify_email, "VERIFIED IPN", "$res\n $req\n $strQuery\n $struery\n  $strQuery2");
}
else {
// send an email
mail($notify_email, "VERIFIED DUPLICATED TRANSACTION", "$res\n $req \n $strQuery\n $struery\n  $strQuery2");
}

    //subscription handling branch
    if ( $txn_type == "subscr_signup"  ||  $txn_type == "subscr_payment"  ) {

      // insert subscriber payment info into paypal_payment_info table
      $strQuery = "insert into paypal_payment_info(paymentstatus,buyer_email,firstname,lastname,street,city,state,zipcode,country,mc_gross,mc_fee,memo,paymenttype,paymentdate,txnid,pendingreason,reasoncode,tax,datecreation) values ('".$payment_status."','".$payer_email."','".$first_name."','".$last_name."','".$address_street."','".$address_city."','".$address_state."','".$address_zip."','".$address_country."','".$mc_gross."','".$mc_fee."','".$memo."','".$payment_type."','".$payment_date."','".$txn_id."','".$pending_reason."','".$reason_code."','".$tax."','".$fecha."')";
      $result = mysql_query($strQuery) or die("Subscription - paypal_payment_info, Query failed:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());


         // insert subscriber info into paypal_subscription_info table
        $strQuery2 = "insert into paypal_subscription_info(subscr_id , sub_event, subscr_date ,subscr_effective,period1,period2, period3, amount1 ,amount2 ,amount3,  mc_amount1,  mc_amount2,  mc_amount3, recurring, reattempt,retry_at, recur_times, username ,password, payment_txn_id, subscriber_emailaddress, datecreation) values ('".$subscr_id."', '".$txn_type."','".$subscr_date."','".$subscr_effective."','".$period1."','".$period2."','".$period3."','".$amount1."','".$amount2."','".$amount3."','".$mc_amount1."','".$mc_amount2."','".$mc_amount3."','".$recurring."','".$reattempt."','".$retry_at."','".$recur_times."','".$username."','".$password."', '".$txn_id."','".$payer_email."','".$fecha."')";
        $result = mysql_query($strQuery2) or die("Subscription - paypal_subscription_info, Query failed:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());


             mail($notify_email, "VERIFIED IPN", "$res\n $req\n $strQuery\n $struery\n  $strQuery2");

    }
}

// if the IPN POST was 'INVALID'...do this


else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
// log for manual investigation

mail($notify_email, "INVALID IPN", "$res\n $req");
}
}
fclose ($fp);
}
?>
```

When I use the online IPN Simulator at https://developer.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/devscr it says that the IPN is successfully sent, however, I see nothing in my database, and I am emailed nothing. What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: It appears your script sends a notification email for a variety of cases. Do you receive any of those emails? If so, can you provide relevant content from them?

Comment: So far, I haven't gotten any e-mails whatsoever. If I do get any, I will post their content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The abundance of `... or die()` messages is a bit concerning - as is the lack of use of any kind of logfile to capture and record errors which may occur once this code is in production (it's ill-advised to just echo error messages, especially if the caller of this script is not you).

I've thrown in some `error_log()` calls, and simplified some of the error messages which will now be shown to the caller, so try the below:

```
<?php

// Revision Notes
// 11/04/11 - changed post back url from https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr to https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
// For more info see below:
// https://www.x.com/content/bulletin-ip-address-expansion-paypal-services
// "ACTION REQUIRED: if you are using IPN (Instant Payment Notification) for Order Management and your IPN listener script is behind a firewall that uses ACL (Access Control List) rules which restrict outbound traffic to a limited number of IP addresses, then you may need to do one of the following: 
// To continue posting back to https://www.paypal.com  to perform IPN validation you will need to update your firewall ACL to allow outbound access to *any* IP address for the servers that host your IPN script
// OR Alternatively, you will need to modify  your IPN script to post back IPNs to the newly created URL https://ipnpb.paypal.com using HTTPS (port 443) and update firewall ACL rules to allow outbound access to the ipnpb.paypal.com IP ranges (see end of message)."

$productionMode = false;
$errorLog = 'ipn_errorlog.txt';

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////Begin Script below./////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

// Switch between Testing and Production Server
if( !$productionMode ){
  $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
}else{
  $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://ipnpb.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
}

// assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$business = $_POST['business'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$mc_gross = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$receiver_id = $_POST['receiver_id'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$num_cart_items = $_POST['num_cart_items'];
$payment_date = $_POST['payment_date'];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$payment_type = $_POST['payment_type'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_gross = $_POST['payment_gross'];
$payment_fee = $_POST['payment_fee'];
$settle_amount = $_POST['settle_amount'];
$memo = $_POST['memo'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$txn_type = $_POST['txn_type'];
$payer_status = $_POST['payer_status'];
$address_street = $_POST['address_street'];
$address_city = $_POST['address_city'];
$address_state = $_POST['address_state'];
$address_zip = $_POST['address_zip'];
$address_country = $_POST['address_country'];
$address_status = $_POST['address_status'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$tax = $_POST['tax'];
$option_name1 = $_POST['option_name1'];
$option_selection1 = $_POST['option_selection1'];
$option_name2 = $_POST['option_name2'];
$option_selection2 = $_POST['option_selection2'];
$for_auction = $_POST['for_auction'];
$invoice = $_POST['invoice'];
$custom = $_POST['custom'];
$notify_version = $_POST['notify_version'];
$verify_sign = $_POST['verify_sign'];
$payer_business_name = $_POST['payer_business_name'];
$payer_id =$_POST['payer_id'];
$mc_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$mc_fee = $_POST['mc_fee'];
$exchange_rate = $_POST['exchange_rate'];
$settle_currency  = $_POST['settle_currency'];
$parent_txn_id  = $_POST['parent_txn_id'];
$pending_reason = $_POST['pending_reason'];
$reason_code = $_POST['reason_code'];


// subscription specific vars

$subscr_id = $_POST['subscr_id'];
$subscr_date = $_POST['subscr_date'];
$subscr_effective  = $_POST['subscr_effective'];
$period1 = $_POST['period1'];
$period2 = $_POST['period2'];
$period3 = $_POST['period3'];
$amount1 = $_POST['amount1'];
$amount2 = $_POST['amount2'];
$amount3 = $_POST['amount3'];
$mc_amount1 = $_POST['mc_amount1'];
$mc_amount2 = $_POST['mc_amount2'];
$mc_amount3 = $_POST['mcamount3'];
$recurring = $_POST['recurring'];
$reattempt = $_POST['reattempt'];
$retry_at = $_POST['retry_at'];
$recur_times = $_POST['recur_times'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

//auction specific vars

$for_auction = $_POST['for_auction'];
$auction_closing_date  = $_POST['auction_closing_date'];
$auction_multi_item  = $_POST['auction_multi_item'];
$auction_buyer_id  = $_POST['auction_buyer_id'];



//DB connect creds and email 
$notify_email =  "hidden_for_StackOverflow";         //email address to which debug emails are sent to
$DB_Server = "hidden_for_StackOverflow"; //your MySQL Server
$DB_Username = "hidden_for_StackOverflow"; //your MySQL User Name
$DB_Password = "hidden_for_StackOverflow"; //your MySQL Password
$DB_DBName = "hidden_for_StackOverflow"; //your MySQL Database Name


if (!$fp) {
  // HTTP ERROR
  error_log( "Failed to connect to PayPal through HTTP\n" , 3 , $errorLog );
} else {
  fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
  while (!feof($fp)) {
    $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
    if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

      //create MySQL connection
      if( !( $Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password) ) ){
        error_log( "Failed to connect to MySQL Server - #".mysql_errno()." - ".mysql_error()."\n" , 3 , $errorLog );
        die( 'Database connection failure' );
      }

      //select database
      if( !( $Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect) ) ){
        error_log( "Failed to connect to MySQL Database - #".mysql_errno()." - ".mysql_error()."\n" , 3 , $errorLog );
        die( 'Database connection failure' );
      }

      // What is the point of this?!
      #$fecha = date("m")."/".date("d")."/".date("Y");
      #$fecha = date("Y").date("m").date("d");
      $fecha = date("Ymd");

      //check if transaction ID has been processed before
      $checkquery = "select txnid from paypal_payment_info where txnid='".(int) $txn_id."'";
      if( !( $sihay = mysql_query($checkquery) ) ){
        error_log( "Duplicate Check - MySQL Query Failed - #".mysql_errno()." - ".mysql_error()."\n" , 3 , $errorLog );
        die( 'Your order experienced an error' );
      }
      if (mysql_num_rows($sihay)== 0){
        //execute query

        if ($txn_type == "cart"){
          $strQuery = "insert into paypal_payment_info(paymentstatus,buyer_email,firstname,lastname,street,city,state,zipcode,country,mc_gross,mc_fee,memo,paymenttype,paymentdate,txnid,pendingreason,reasoncode,tax,datecreation) values ('".$payment_status."','".$payer_email."','".$first_name."','".$last_name."','".$address_street."','".$address_city."','".$address_state."','".$address_zip."','".$address_country."','".$mc_gross."','".$mc_fee."','".$memo."','".$payment_type."','".$payment_date."','".$txn_id."','".$pending_reason."','".$reason_code."','".$tax."','".$fecha."')";

          if( !( $result = mysql_query($strQuery) ) ){
            error_log( "Adding Payment - MySQL Query Failed - #".mysql_errno()." - ".mysql_error()."\n" , 3 , $errorLog );
            die( 'Your order experienced an error' );
          }
          for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_cart_items; $i++) {
            $struery = "insert into paypal_cart_info(txnid,itemnumber,itemname,os0,on0,os1,on1,quantity,invoice,custom) values ('".$txn_id."','".$_POST["item_number".$i]."','".$_POST["item_name".$i]."','".$_POST["option_name1_".$i]."','".$_POST["option_selection1_".$i]."','".$_POST["option_name2_".$i]."','".$_POST["option_selection2_".$i]."','".$_POST["quantity".$i]."','".$invoice."','".$custom."')";
            if( !( $result = mysql_query($struery) ) ){
              error_log( "Adding Item #$i - MySQL Query Failed - #".mysql_errno()." - ".mysql_error()."\n" , 3 , $errorLog );
              die( 'There was a problem processing your purchase' );
            }
          }
        }
        else{
          $strQuery = "insert into paypal_payment_info(paymentstatus,buyer_email,firstname,lastname,street,city,state,zipcode,country,mc_gross,mc_fee,itemnumber,itemname,os0,on0,os1,on1,quantity,memo,paymenttype,paymentdate,txnid,pendingreason,reasoncode,tax,datecreation) values ('".$payment_status."','".$payer_email."','".$first_name."','".$last_name."','".$address_street."','".$address_city."','".$address_state."','".$address_zip."','".$address_country."','".$mc_gross."','".$mc_fee."','".$item_number."','".$item_name."','".$option_name1."','".$option_selection1."','".$option_name2."','".$option_selection2."','".$quantity."','".$memo."','".$payment_type."','".$payment_date."','".$txn_id."','".$pending_reason."','".$reason_code."','".$tax."','".$fecha."')";
          if( !( $result = mysql_query($strQuery) ){
            error_log( "Adding Non-Cart Item - MySQL Query Failed - #".mysql_errno()." - ".mysql_error()."\n" , 3 , $errorLog );
            die( 'There was a problem processing your purchase' );
          }
        }


        // send an email in any case
        echo "Verified";
        # There is no $strQuery2
        mail($notify_email, "VERIFIED IPN", "$res\n $req\n $strQuery\n $struery\n  $strQuery2");
      }
      else {
        // send an email
        # There is no $strQuery2
        error_log( "Duplicate Transaction\n" , 3 , $errorLog );
        mail($notify_email, "VERIFIED DUPLICATED TRANSACTION", "$res\n $req \n $strQuery\n $struery\n  $strQuery2");
      }

      //subscription handling branch
      if ( $txn_type == "subscr_signup"  ||  $txn_type == "subscr_payment"  ) {

        // insert subscriber payment info into paypal_payment_info table
        $strQuery = "insert into paypal_payment_info(paymentstatus,buyer_email,firstname,lastname,street,city,state,zipcode,country,mc_gross,mc_fee,memo,paymenttype,paymentdate,txnid,pendingreason,reasoncode,tax,datecreation) values ('".$payment_status."','".$payer_email."','".$first_name."','".$last_name."','".$address_street."','".$address_city."','".$address_state."','".$address_zip."','".$address_country."','".$mc_gross."','".$mc_fee."','".$memo."','".$payment_type."','".$payment_date."','".$txn_id."','".$pending_reason."','".$reason_code."','".$tax."','".$fecha."')";
        if( !( $result = mysql_query($strQuery) ) ){
          error_log( "Adding Subscription - MySQL Query Failed - #".mysql_errno()." - ".mysql_error()."\n" , 3 , $errorLog );
          die( 'There was a problem processing your Subscription' );
        }

         // insert subscriber info into paypal_subscription_info table
        $strQuery2 = "insert into paypal_subscription_info(subscr_id , sub_event, subscr_date ,subscr_effective,period1,period2, period3, amount1 ,amount2 ,amount3,  mc_amount1,  mc_amount2,  mc_amount3, recurring, reattempt,retry_at, recur_times, username ,password, payment_txn_id, subscriber_emailaddress, datecreation) values ('".$subscr_id."', '".$txn_type."','".$subscr_date."','".$subscr_effective."','".$period1."','".$period2."','".$period3."','".$amount1."','".$amount2."','".$amount3."','".$mc_amount1."','".$mc_amount2."','".$mc_amount3."','".$recurring."','".$reattempt."','".$retry_at."','".$recur_times."','".$username."','".$password."', '".$txn_id."','".$payer_email."','".$fecha."')";
        if( !( $result = mysql_query($strQuery2) ) ){
          error_log( "Adding Subscription - MySQL Query Failed - #".mysql_errno()." - ".mysql_error()."\n" , 3 , $errorLog );
          die( 'There was a problem processing your Subscription' );
        }

        mail($notify_email, "VERIFIED IPN", "$res\n $req\n $strQuery\n $struery\n  $strQuery2");
      }
    }

    // if the IPN POST was 'INVALID'...do this
    else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
      // log for manual investigation
      error_log( "Invalid IPN - $res\n $req\n" , 3 , $errorLog );
      mail($notify_email, "INVALID IPN", "$res\n $req");
    }
    else{
      error_log( "Unformed & Invalid IPN - $res\n $req\n" , 3 , $errorLog );
    }
  }
  fclose ($fp);
}
```

(No warranty provided.)

Comment: Ok. I just tried it, and still have nothing getting sent to either me or my database.

Comment: You calling it directly, or through the PayPal tool? Have you tried both? Have you tried calling it using a test page containing a POST form with the expected field values? If you are seeing nothing, that may be because it is not being triggered at all. (An overly simple idea/bug, but, Occam's Razor.)

Comment: Ok. I have tried some different things. I used PayPal's tool with production mode off, and got nothing. I tried using their tool with production mode on (obviously creating an invalid situation), and got the expected response (an email with the contents of the IPN). I tried accessing the IPN listener directly with a web browser, and was emailed about that as well (however, with no IPN request included, due to the fact that none was sent).

Comment: Yeah... just checked the php error log. turns out that the script was trying to write to the error log, but had file permissions errors. I used the newly accessible error log to find that this was the error: "Adding Payment - MySQL Query Failed". Turns out that it was a typo in the database field for 'zipcode'. It was typed as 'zipode'. Should I feel stupid for losing **8 hours** of my day due to one typo? Also, thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Welcome to the world of the coder - losing hours upon hours and performing drastic redevelopments of swathes of code only to find a missing ".", ";" or the like is par for the course. But, we learn, we stop making simple mistakes (start making complex ones, then stop making complex ones and start making simple ones again) - it's a growing process. Happy to have helped.

Comment: Thanks! That helped me update my code to use ssl:// and 443 in the line with fsockopen.